# What are my best ASP.Net GridView replacement options?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

We currently use a GridView to display 1000+ rows of data.  Minimum requirement for replacement is a fixed header row, fixed footer and columns would be a plus.

This would have to work across IE 6 and greater.

I've heard good things about Infragistics, but the demo on their page is slow.

So what are my best options?  jQuery? YUI? other 3rd party?

Answer (score 1):

I would skip the server side components and look into jquery/javascript. Send a normal table in markup to the client then let the browser ajax data in as it needs it.

jqGrid springs to mind, or extjs.

Comment: Aren't those slow though?  I'm talking about 1000+ rows of data, sometimes 15 columns wide.

Comment: In modern browsers - no - and remember the data has to come down the wire in some format anyway - either html, xml or json

Comment: ie 6 isn't so modern though, but I don't think I'll have to worry about ie 6 much longer.  I think ie7+ is the new target.

Comment: @Homer If you're using AJAX, why would you send 1000+ rows of data at a time. Why not just send 10-20 rows at a time?

Comment: Users don't want to page, they want to see everything.

Comment: @Homer Giving the user all the data doens't make sense. Are they going to scroll through 1000s to find the one they want? I'm battling how to best handle this myself and I think filtering the results is better than dumping 1000s of records on the user.

Answer (score 1):

Try Obout's autoscrolling grid control.

http://www.obout.com/grid/grid_auto_scroll.aspx

Comment: Does this also handle horizontal scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/)